# Why is the NOISE amplitude reverse in frequency domain from my Original audio stream?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, noise

We currently found a strange and very serious issue in our infotainment system that has confused us deeply-- Our qnx system keeps playing strong noise instead of valid audio stream.  What's worse, we can't collect any logs or audio stream within the system, but only some videos recorded by our customers using their phones.
By observing the audio (split from the videos), we found a very strange feature: the spectrogram indicates that the noise has a reverse in amplitude compared with the original audio in the frequency domain.
[Noise and normal audio compared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1JG3.jpg)

[Turning signal  -  noise and valid audio stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RojZX.png)

[touch sound: noise and valid audio stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXZ5n.png)
Although the audio recorded might be a little distorted, this feature is quite clear.
We did an experiment importing audio data (in the format of 16 bit, 1 channel) in a different format (8 bit, 2 channels), and got a similar result: the channel 1 and channel 2 are reverse in amplitude in the frequency domain.  So I'm suspecting there's a connection between these distortions.
Could anyone provide some constructive suggestions about how and why the audio stream could possibly distorted and transformed like this?
[16 bit mono audio imported as 8 bit 2-channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EnYc.jpg)
And why the frequency spectrogram shows amplitude reverse when I read a 16-bit mono audio stream in 8 bit 2 channels?

We are now trying to figure out first how can a normal audio stream be transformed into a frequency-amplitude reverse signal, and then find out what may cause this issue in our audio system, which has a long route from Android, qnx, dsp, A2B cable and smart Amplifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a somewhat unclear, so I'm trying to extract what you're trying to say by making educated guesses: When you say "reverse amplitude" I guess you're referring to this here: [image: Aliasing artifacts]

This is most likely an aliasing artifact, caused by a signal being recorded with very strong spectral components which frequencies lie above the sampling [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency). Don't interpret too much into this, other than the information that your customers' phones are not up to the task of reliably capturing what's going on.

Now regarding the noise you're showing there. That's broadband noise covering the whole spectrum (white noise). The way to generate this digitally is to have uniformly random in time distributed samples that will go from one end of the value range to the other. This can happen if you clip the signal without saturating (integer overflow), or if you're playing back an *unsigned integer* format as *signed integer* (or vice versa). Or it can also happen, you're randomly, but at a very high rate are experiencing buffer underruns, so the system is rapidly starting and stopping playback of the audio signal, which will cause both high *crest factor* amplitude modulation, but due to the time jumps also *phase moduluation* as well.

Here's a checklist:

Do the set playback parameters match the audio format?

- signed vs. unsigned?
- bits per sample, with or without padding?
- sample rate?

Are the audio buffers large enough, and is your program able to keep up with playback? Do you have enough buffers in flight so that the audio stream can play uninterrupted, when the next buffer must be filled by the application?